# I'm confused about a negative point that I received

Tags: support, reputation

You can see in the following screenshots that I've received a negative point, for some unapparent reason, on this one question (*What Biblical scripture is used to support the concept of waiting for God to give direction?*):

[image]

[image]

The link itself (from my reputation tab) takes me down to [What Biblical scripture is used to support the concept of waiting for God to give direction?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/45234/what-biblical-scripture-is-used-to-support-the-concept-of-waiting-for-god-to-giv/45251#45251)
which points to user24490's comment.

I'm wondering why I have received a negative point on this question when I never answered nor even so much as commented on it. Can anyone shed any light or share any idea as to why this happened?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [help center documentation on situations where you can lose reputation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), down-voting other people's answers costs you 1 reputation. This is to avoid new users going on down-voting rampages or making revenge down-votes.

While you may not have answered or commented on the question, you evidently downvoted one of the answers.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder, Caleb. That's exactly it.